# How to get records of last month of this year,

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to fetch records of last month of this year, but i am getting records of past years also. please help me out

I had a query like this:

```
select EmpCode,EventDate1 as EventDate,InTime,
case when OutTime is null then 'N/A' else Outtime end as OutTime from    
TMS_HOURCALC WHERE DATEPART(m, EventDate) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
and empcode='13658'

GROUP BY EmpCode, InTime,OutTime, EventDate1,intime1     
order by intime1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check year condition as well.

```
select EmpCode,EventDate1 as EventDate,InTime,
case when OutTime is null then 'N/A' else Outtime end as OutTime from    
TMS_HOURCALC WHERE 
DATEPART(m, EventDate) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(y, EventDate) = DATEPART(y, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
and empcode='13658'

GROUP BY EmpCode, InTime,OutTime, EventDate1,intime1     
order by intime1;
```

Comment: I tried executing but i got only 1 record with my above query without year tag i got 39 records!

Comment: do the remaining 38 records belongs to previous years?

Comment: In 39 records, 23 belongs to 2012 and remaining 16 belongs to this year!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I replaced y with yyyy then i got answer